# How to plot a social network in r including the different kinds of relations?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with 3 columns.

```
A    B     relation highlight
Lisa Gary Father 1
Maria Lisa Mother 1
Steven Carl Father 1
Tom Maria Lovers 0
Lea Carl Father 0
Ryan Susan Lover 1
...
```

B is to A what is described in the column `relation`
Is there a way to plot a social network of that in r that doesn't only connect the A and B but also contains the information of the 3rd column in some way (maybe by different colors)? I would also like to be able to differentiate the dots by the 4th column `highlight` possibly by giving the dots a different colour.

Comment: I know this slightly complex "igraph" library: https://r.igraph.org/articles/igraph.html
You can visualize a lot with it, insert captions and colors, thicken strength of the lines and so on.., i needed to use it in my psychology-studium a few times. But didn't need to dive deep into it.